# Background and other windows shine through

Tags: windows, transparency

Since I upgraded to Windows 10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad L530 (with Intel HD Graphics 4000), other windows or the desktop and its wallpaper shine through on dark background areas of open windows as you can see in the following screenshot from "Visual Studio Code":

[Transparency bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTYVL.jpg)

The error  occurs in any application that has a more or less dark background.
It seems to me that window layering is not completely deactivated globally.

What is the reason for this and why is it enabled?
Is there a registry setting for that?

Thanks in advance,
NasenSchnarch

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I played around with 
UxTheme Multi-Patcher some time ago and its theme engine was started after logon. That engine set the background transparency to one step below full opaque. Without it, everything is fine.